# Position change makes image go the right

Tags: html, image, header, position

When I change the position of my image to fixed it goes off to the right, I cannot figure out how to get it back to the center of my page and still use the position:fixed attribute. Please help

Thank you ahead of time!

```
CSS:
    header {
        height: 60px;
        color: #413659;
        background-color: #413659;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

#logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<header>

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IdtgpVa.png" alt="DP" id="logo">

</header>
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2eqYe/ What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-left: -50px;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
        left:50%;
    }
```

updated [jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/2eqYe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)  from CSS3

```
    left: 45%;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8utY/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for your CSS:

```
header {
        height: 60px;
        color: #413659;
        background-color: #413659;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

#logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-left: 45%;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: This should give you a centered logo. I didn,t use 50% because, this moves the logo to the right. Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d67M6/ .